# What is the mathematical name for the "equation of life"?

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes, soft-question, terminology

I have seen this expression [here](https://youtu.be/VCb2AMN87cg?t=822)

[image]

and I am curious to know if there is a more one-to-one, unequivocal way to reference this equation (e.g. eponym).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is certainly not accepted as **the** "equation of life", but it does fall under the broad category of [Birth-death processes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Birth%E2%80%93death_process), which are Markov chains commonly used to model, as you might guess, population growth, amongst many other things.

Edit: Although there are very few results for "random multiplicative growth", I think this is an apt description of what it is actually doing.

Edit 2: This is most definitely **not** Geometric Brownian Motion! GBM Is indeed the continuous-time analogue of this though. As in, a certain scaling limit of this process converges in distribution to a GBM, much the same as a scaling limit of a random walk converges to a normal BM. However, to say that this is a GBM or a coin-flip walk of a BM would be a huge error!

Comment: I want to accept your answer, but since I ran across the specific context of this expression, and summarized it in an answer, I wonder if you would mind splicing your general idea with this specific use for GBM.

Comment: Thank you for your edit. At the start, when you say "This" what exactly are you referring to? The coin flip with different payoffs experiment, I presume? And this coin flip with payoffs set up would be the discrete-time analogue of a GBM? I found "the" paper on this [here](https://www.nature.com/articles/s41567-019-0732-0.pdf?proof=t). I presume it is mathematically correct.

Comment: By "this" I mean your "random multiplicate growth" is NOT a GBM. It is a discrete Markov chain with some analogous properties, but you will get weird looks if you claim it is a GBM.

Comment: I am very curious to picture what the transition matrix would look like.

Comment: It will be an infinite transition matrix with for each x having 1/2 chance of going to 1.5x and 1/2 change of going to .6x.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer within the exact context where the question arose (linked video in the OP):

> At [LML (London Mathematical Laboratory)](https://lml.org.uk/people/ole-peters-2/) we affectionately call it the equation of life.

And the answer (within this very niche context) is [geometric Brownian motion](https://lml.org.uk/people/ole-peters-2/), which is the continuous version of coin toss model in finances, illustrating non-ergodic processes: A fair coin toss determines at every round of the game, whether the capital invested $C$ increases $50$ percent, or decreases by $40$ percent, for example, starting at $C_0=\$\,1$. The time average will be driven by the multiplicative fact that there is an expected $10$ percent loss every two rounds: $1.5\times 0.6=0.9,$ leading inexorably to an individual's ruin over time, despite the fact that the expected value of the random variable $C$ is $\mathbb E[C]= \frac 1 2 1.5 + \frac 1 2 0.6=1.05,$ i.e. a gain of $5$ percent.

This is beautifully illustrated in this [video by Ole Peters](https://youtu.be/CCLtQHL-VUs), and could be plotted on a quick Monte Carlo simulation as the discrepancy between the ensemble average of $9$ rounds of the game (which will be positive and progressively (larger ensembles) more clearly exponential as in the dashed red line below (log-linear plot)):

[image]

and the long-term average fate of a single individual, which will be ruinous for each individual ($n=10$) despite some early "hot hands":

[image]

Mathematically,

$$\begin{align}
\Delta C &= C(t+\Delta t) - C(t)\\
&=C(t)r_t -C(t)
\end{align}$$

with the ratio $r_t$ at point $t$ being the sum of a deterministic part, and a random part that is symmetric: $1+r_t=\mu + \sigma.$ Re-writing the prior equation using a Gaussian for the random part with variance $\Delta t:$

$$\begin{align}
\Delta C &= C(t+\Delta t) - C(t)\\
&=C(t)\left( \mu \Delta t + \sigma \mathcal N(0,\Delta t)\right)
\end{align}$$

which will assume a limit value of

$$\begin{align}
dC &=C(t)\left( \mu dt + \sigma \mathcal N(0,dt)\right)\\
&=C(t)\left( \mu dt + \sigma dW\right)
\end{align}$$